# set all selected values greater than 0 equal to 1: mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

New to SQL. Is it possible to set a summed value equal to 1 if it is any number greater than 0. I don't want to change the number in the database, just want to run a select to get whether or not the sum of the group of values is more than 0 or 0.

The data looks like this

```
 col1 | col2
  1      1
  1      1
  1      0
  2      0
  3      1
  3      1
  3      1
  3      1
```

I currently can get it to this

```
select table.col1, sum(table.col2)
from messages
group by table.col1;

 col1 | col2
  1      2
  2      0
  3      4
```

I'd like it to look like this

```
col1 | col2
 1      1
 2      0
 3      1
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are you getting an `id` column in your result when you don't have `id` in the `SELECT` clause?

Comment: And why aren't the IDs in your result the same as the IDs in the original table? There's no row with `col1 = 3` and `id = 3`.

Comment: Sorry. That was an example table. I changed it

Comment: `CASE WHEN SUM(col2) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `IF`:

```
SELECT col1, IF(SUM(col2) > 0, 1, 0) AS col2
FROM messages
GROUP BY col1
```

You can also use the SQL standard `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT col1,
       CASE WHEN SUM(col2) > 0
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS col2
FROM messages
GROUP BY col1
```

Comment: thanks for providing two examples, they both work. The first needs one more "(" after "IF"

Comment: actually, it needed one less `)`. Fixed.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use a test within your query, as a new column. something like this :

```
Select col1, if col1 > 0 then 1 else 0 from table1
```

Though I am not sure about the exact syntax, you might want to look into this direction

Comment: Your syntax is totally wrong. You're closer to the `CASE` syntax, but you don't have that right, either.